# How to write to a specific position inside a HTML in Python?

Tags: python

I have a large HTML file and I want to write to a specific position inside the HTML file, but I do not want to write on the original file that's why I create a copy of it. Currently, I have a code that looks like this:

```
import shutil

shutil.copy2('./file.html', './new_file.html')
f = open('new_file.html', 'w') 
content = '<tr><td>New value<td></tr>'
# TODO: I need to write the above content after the <tbody> tag in HTML,
# please note that I have just one <tbody> tag in my HTML file
f.close()
```

Any ideas how to find write the `content` variable after the `tbody` tag in my HTML?

Comment: Opening and reading in the original file should help.

Comment: @usr2564301 Why does it matter whether I read the origin or the new file? I do not know how can I find where the `<tbody>` tag is located.

Comment: You open the new file for *writing*. You do know that you cannot insert data "in" a file? Open the original, modify, write to new file.

Comment: Please share your an example of your HTML itself.

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius It's a large file, about 3-4 thousand lines. But, there is just one `<tbody></tbody>` in the file. I need to find where the `<tbody>` ends. So that I can write the content there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to approach this.  One option is to use a template, i.e. some known value in the HTML file that you search for and replace.  A common templating engine for Python is jinja2. Here's an example:

The HTML file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
{{ replace_me }}
</body>
</html>
```

Now the Python code:

```
from jinja2 import Template
with open('file.html') as f:
    t = Template(f.read())

# Create a dict with template keys and their values
vals = {'replace_me': 'some new text'}

with open('new_file.html') as f:
    f.write(t.render(vals))
```

The rendered HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
some new text
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic way to do it w/ default datatypes of python (w/o templates, additional libraries and so on):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil

f = open('file.html', 'r')
old_file_content = f.read()
f.close()

# print the file that was read
print(old_file_content)

replacee = '<td>Old value<td>'
replacement = '<td>New value<td>'
new_file_cntent = old_file_content.replace(replacee, replacement)

# print the modified content, for comparison
print(new_file_cntent)
```

Here is the output:

```
mindaugasb@python:~/workspace/StackOverflow $ ./insert_text_to_html.py 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test title!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Foo</th>
                <th>Bar</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Old value<td> <--- The part that will be replaced
                <td>W00t!</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test title!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Foo</th>
                <th>Bar</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>New value<td> <-- the part that replaced the old part
                <td>W00t!</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

After that, it is not difficult to add the modified contents to a new file or do whatever ones hear pleases.